# Get facebook email address from login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using [hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js) to have users create accounts and sign in with facebook. However, I need to use the user's facebook email address since this is used to send the user a confirmation of purchase.

Because the user can choose to not allow us to have his/her email address, I am left with an empty slot, thus the user never receiving confirmation of orders or downloadable files purchased through the system.

I've tried using the facebook user ID, but the email format is `username@facebook.com`. I can retrieve the user's ID and email (if allowed), but not the username.

Can we retrieve this and if so, how ?

Comment: Field `username` does not exist any more in API v2. And not every user does even _have_ an email address on file with Facebook (f.e. if they signed up using their mobile), and there’s other reasons you might not get one back from the API even if the user gives permission. If you need an email address, then implement an extra step to let the user provide one directly.

Comment: @CBroe So from what I gather, there is no method of gathering this information, let alone a guarantee there is any data to retrieve...?

Comment: You can get an email address under certain conditions – and under some others, you can not. So you should not build any kind of functionality that _relies_ on it, resp. provide alternative means for users to supply an email address.

Answer (score 0):

I scratched my head too on how to fetch emails from FB, cause the response object in the documentation [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web] paragraph **Make API calls** looks different from what it is returned.

You may want to look at:
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api]
and add parameters.

Here using version 2.5:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : {your-app-id},
  status : true,
  cookie : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  oauth : true,
  version    : 'v2.5'
});
```

Following the documentation, once logged:

`FB.api('/me', function(response) {console.log(response) })`

response has only `_ID` and `name` despite permissions are granted.

You can retrieve the email, *if existing*, by **also** specifying `fields` parameters against `FB.api`:

`FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});`